# IOS: ad hoc provisioning

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution

I have this problem:

Invalid Profile: distribution build entitlements must have get-task-allow set to false

I know that I must set

```
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<true/>
```

in entitlements.plist but in xcode 4.3 i don't find this file, what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add Entitlements file to your project.

You can find detailed explanation at http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/common-questions/i-get-an-unable-to-download-error-when-installing-my-application. Scroll down to 'Missing Entitlements'.

Comment: To create entitlements file in Xcode 4 just create a new plist file from new file menu item and then change its type to iPhone Entitlements plist. You can change file type by selecting the file in Project Navigator then right clicking in the editor on the right, select Property List type and finally select iPhone Entitlements plist.

Answer (score 2):

From:

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/535398-invalid-profile-distribution-build-entitlements-must-have-get-task-allow-set-to-false-

As of XCode 4.3, this is handled automatically. What seems to confuse some developers is when they upload their IPA to TestFlight and get an error stating that get-task-allow must be set to false. This indicates that either:

- You created an Entitlements.plist file and set get-task-allow to true in an older version of Xcode
- You are signing your application with a Development Provisioning Profile

What drove me mad is that I could not get my Distribution Provisioning Profile to work and always got this error. Strangely, if I used a Developer Provisioning Profile, it worked. WTF.